# Proper way to use readdir() and stat() together in minGW-W64 to get file/directory information and avoid max path issues?

Tags: c, mingw-w64

I didn't ask this question as well as it should have been worded when I first posted it. So, I'm editing a bit here.

There's three blocks of code below, all of which read the contents of a directory and attempt to get the stats on the contents. All three work, except when the path/file name reaches 260 characters or more.

In all cases, `readdir()` returns the directory contents without issue but `stat()` fails with the error that the file or directory doesn't exist.

The first block passes a pointer to the path and file name to `stat()`. The second changes the working directory and then passes a pointer to just the file name. The third attempts to use the prefix `//?/` with a fully qualified path to extend the max path accepted. None make a difference. Otherwise, all work fine except for long paths.

My question is is there a way to get this to work such that `stat()` won't fail for a file name that is the longest that the OS will accept. I'm using Windows 7 and just type a file name until the input box won't accept more characters. Or, is there a better method overall that perhaps doesn't require a pointer to a path but a different identifier?

Thank you.

---

I think the answer to specific question concerning `stat()` is that you cannot extend the max length past 260 with the prefix because the prefix is for Win32 functions only and not POSIX functions. And there are no other options.

---

Original question:
In minGW-W64, is there another way to get file information other than repeating the path name in the `stat()` function as below?

From inspecting the `dirent.h` header, there appears to be nothing in the `dirent struct` to simply step through the records in the directory after reading without having to repeat the path.

It's not difficult to repeat the path in the `stat()` function but it seems to apply different size limits for the max path and i can't get the prefix of `\\?\` or `\\.\` to work with it. The `\\?\` prefix fails altogether; `\\.\` returns the stats but still fails at the same size limit as without it.

It seems that there ought to be a better way since `readdir()` is returning the file/directories and there should be an identifier but I don't see one available. Or to be able to pass just `ep->d_name` to `stat()` rather than having to include the path, which is what is in `fl_name` below, for `p` is just a pointer to the point in `fl_name` after the path.

Thank you.
More complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main ( void )
 {
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;
    struct stat info;
    int rc, q, l, i = 0, v = 0;
    const char *path = NULL;
    char *fl_name,
         *p = NULL;
    const char *sec_path = "../../databases/";
    unsigned int len_sec_path = strlen( sec_path );

    fl_name = malloc( len_sec_path + 261 );
    // Want p to be at the point in fl_name to write the actual file and directory names in order to get the stats.
    // memcpy returns the pointer to the destination; so, just add the length of path to that to get to the end.
    p = memcpy( fl_name, sec_path, len_sec_path + 1 ) + len_sec_path;

    if ( ( dp = opendir( fl_name ) ) == NULL )
      {
        printf( "Failed to open the directory of: %s", fl_name );
        return 1;
      }
    
    while ( ep = readdir( dp ) )
      { 
        memcpy( p, ep->d_name, ( l = strlen( ep->d_name ) ) > 259 ? 260 : l + 1 );
        printf( "%d, %s\n", strlen( fl_name ), fl_name );
        if ( ( rc = stat( fl_name, &info ) ) != 0 )
          { 
            printf( "%s\n", fl_name ); 
            printf( "rc = %d, errno : %d, strerror : %s\n", rc, errno, strerror( errno ) ); 
            continue;
          }
      }  
   return 0;
 }
```

Version 2.

```
int main ( void )
 {
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;
    struct stat info;
    int rc, q, l, i = 0, v = 0;
    const char *path = NULL;
    char *fl_name,
         *p = NULL,
         name;
    const char *sec_path = "../../databases/";
    unsigned int len_sec_path = strlen( sec_path );

    fl_name = malloc( len_sec_path + 261 );
    // Want p to be at the point in fl_name to write the actual file and directory names in order to get the stats.
    // memcpy returns the pointer to the destination; so, just add the length of path to that to get to the end.
    p = memcpy( fl_name, sec_path, len_sec_path + 1 ) + len_sec_path;
    
    char *buffer;
    if ( (buffer = _getcwd( NULL, 0 )) == NULL )
      {
       printf( "Failed to get current working directory." );
       return 1;
      }

    printf( "buffer is %s\n", buffer );

    if ( ( dp = opendir( fl_name ) ) == NULL )
      {
        printf( "Failed to open the directory of: %s", fl_name );
        return 1;
      }
        
    if ( _chdir( sec_path ) ) 
      {
        printf( "Couldn't change directory." );
        return 1;
      }

    while ( ep = readdir( dp ) )
      { 
        memcpy( p, ep->d_name, ( l = strlen( ep->d_name ) ) > 259 ? 260 : l + 1 );
        printf( "%d, %s\n", strlen( fl_name ), fl_name );
        if ( ( rc = stat( p, &info ) ) != 0 )
          { 
            printf( "%s\n", fl_name ); 
            printf( "rc = %d, errno : %d, strerror : %s\n", rc, errno, strerror( errno ) ); 
            continue;
          }    
      }  

    if ( _chdir( buffer ) ) 
      {
        printf( "Couldn't change directory." );
        return 1;
      }

   printf( "buffer is %s\n", buffer );

   free( buffer );
   return 0;
 }
```

Code attempting to use the `\\?\` prefix to increase max path. I thought version 2 above was working and I thought that this version with the prefix was working but discovered that neither really works. Even when the directory is changed such that a pointer to the file name is passed to `stat()`, without the need for a path, it appears that the path is still included in the max in some manner because if the path plus filename reaches 260 `stat()` fails, stating that the file cannot be found. I guess it's not that big a deal, for I can catch and handle the errors and inform the user.  It's just irritating that the user can use filenames in their directories that the OS will accept but I can't display them in a UI within an application.

```
int get_dir_2( void )    
 {    
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;
    struct _stat info;
    int rc, q, i = 0, v = 0;

    char *fl_name,
         *p = NULL,
         *path = NULL;
    const char *sec_path = "../../databases/",
                   *prefix = "\\\\?\\"; 

    unsigned int l, len_sec_path = strlen( sec_path );

    if ( _chdir( sec_path ) ) 
      {
        printf( "Couldn't change directory." );
        return 1;
      }

    char *dirCWD;

    if ( (dirCWD = _getcwd( NULL, 0 )) == NULL )
      {
       printf( "Failed to get current working directory." );
       return 1;
      }

    path = "";
    l = strlen( prefix ) + strlen( dirCWD ) + strlen( path );
    fl_name = malloc( l + 301 );
    p = ( fl_name + l );

    sprintf( fl_name, "%s%s%s", prefix, dirCWD, path );
    printf( "fl_name is %s\n", fl_name );

    if ( _chdir( fl_name ) ) 
      {
        printf( "Couldn't change directory." );
        return 1;
      }

    if ( ( dp = opendir( fl_name ) ) == NULL )
      {
        printf( "Failed to open the directory of: %s", fl_name );
        return 1;
      }
    
    while ( ep = readdir( dp ) )
      { 
        memcpy( p, ep->d_name, ( l = strlen( ep->d_name ) ) > 259 ? 261 : l + 1 );
        //printf( "%d, %s\n", strcmp( ep->d_name, p ), p );
        printf( "%d, %s\n", strlen( fl_name ), fl_name );
        if ( ( rc = _stat( p, &info ) ) != 0 )
          { 
            printf( "%s\n", fl_name ); 
            printf( "rc = %d, errno : %d, strerror : %s\n", rc, errno, strerror( errno ) ); 
            continue;
          }
       printf( "ctime : %d, mtime : %d, atime : %d\n", info.st_ctime, info.st_mtime, info.st_atime ); 
      }  

   free( fl_name );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228390/discussion-between-david-c-rankin-and-gary).

Comment: The answer to the updated question is always make sure any storage holding a `/path/filename.ext` is `PATH_MAX` characters long -- even if your find that a header is only using `260` chars for storage. The reason we have `PATH_MAX` is so that all conforming implementations can agree that no matter what the `path + filename` is -- it will fit in storage of `PATH_MAX` characters. Even if you only have `260` chars, if you use a `PATH_MAX` size buffer -- your users won't break your code doing something wonky. I'd rather have 10,000 chars to many, than 1 char to few...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several areas where I suspect you had your problem occurring, but without validation checks to catch the errors when they occur, and with your use of non-standard C functions, it is difficult to tell exactly where the problem lay. In addition to the validations, you were attempting to use pointer-arithmetic on a `void*` pointer with:

```
p = memcpy( fl_name, sec_path, len_sec_path + 1 ) + len_sec_path;
```

which can also cause problems.

You use `_getcwd()` and `_chdir()` which are not standard C functions. I'm not sure where those were obtained.

To avoid the problems, use only valid C functions and validate every step in your program that is necessary to the continued defined operation of your code. For example, validate every allocation:

```
#define FN_BUF_LEN 260      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
    const char *sec_path = "../../cb/";
    
    size_t len_sec_path = strlen (sec_path);

    if (!(fl_name = malloc (len_sec_path + FN_BUF_LEN + 1))) {  /* validate malloc */
        perror ("malloc-fl_name");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Do not attempt pointer arithmetic on the `void*` return of `memcpy()`, e.g.

```
    /* Want p to be at the point in fl_name to write the actual file and 
     * directory names in order to get the stats. memcpy returns the pointer to the
     * destination; so, just add the length of path to that to get to the end.
     */
    p = memcpy (fl_name, sec_path, len_sec_path + FN_BUF_LEN + 1);
    p += len_sec_path;      /* memcpy() is type void*, cannot use with arithmetic */
```

Validate every call to `chddir()`, e.g.

```
    if (chdir (sec_path) == -1) {                   /* _chdir() is not std C */
        perror ("chdir()");                         /* validate result */
        return 1;
    }
```

and

```
    if (chdir (buffer)) {
        perror ("chdir()");
        return 1;
    }
```

Putting all of the pieces together and adding additional thoughts in-line as comments below, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FN_BUF_LEN 260      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {
    
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;
    struct stat info;
    
    char *fl_name,
        *p = NULL, 
        *buffer = NULL;
        
    // const char *sec_path = "../../databases/";
    const char *sec_path = "../../cb/";
    
    size_t len_sec_path = strlen (sec_path);

    if (!(fl_name = malloc (len_sec_path + FN_BUF_LEN + 1))) {  /* validate malloc */
        perror ("malloc-fl_name");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    /* Want p to be at the point in fl_name to write the actual file and 
     * directory names in order to get the stats. memcpy returns the pointer to the
     * destination; so, just add the length of path to that to get to the end.
     */
    p = memcpy (fl_name, sec_path, len_sec_path + FN_BUF_LEN + 1);
    p += len_sec_path;      /* memcpy() is type void*, cannot use with arithmetic */
    
    if ((buffer = getcwd (NULL, 0)) == NULL) {      /* _getcwd() is not std C */
        perror ("getcwd()");                        /* validate result */
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("buffer is %s\n", buffer);

    if ((dp = opendir (fl_name)) == NULL) {
        printf ("Failed to open the directory of: %s", fl_name);
        return 1;
    }

    if (chdir (sec_path) == -1) {                   /* _chdir() is not std C */
        perror ("chdir()");                         /* validate result */
        return 1;
    }

    while ((ep = readdir (dp))) {
        size_t l = strlen (ep->d_name);             /* declare vars in scope needed */
        if (l > 259) {                              /* validate length before memcpy */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: %s length %u exceeds allowable.\n", ep->d_name, l);
            continue;
        }
        /* filter the "." and ".." directories out */
        if (strcmp (ep->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp (ep->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        
        memcpy (p, ep->d_name, l + 1);
        printf ("%u, %s\n", strlen (fl_name), fl_name);
        
        int rc = stat (p, &info);
        if (rc == -1) {
            printf ("%s\n", fl_name);
            printf ("rc = %d, errno : %d, strerror : %s\n", rc, errno, strerror (errno));
            continue;
        }
    }

    if (chdir (buffer)) {
        perror ("chdir()");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("buffer is %s\n", buffer);

    free (buffer);      /* free all memory you have allocated */
    free (fl_name);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Testing on Win7 with MinGW 5.1 (old TDM-MinGW) and changing `sec_path` to `"../../cb/"` so there are files and directories present there on the Win7 guest, you would have:

```
>bin\readdir_prob.exe
buffer is C:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp
18, ../../cb/debugtest
21, ../../cb/default.conf
19, ../../cb/farmtotals
22, ../../cb/farmtotalsfmt
14, ../../cb/first
15, ../../cb/helopp
19, ../../cb/matrixsolv
16, ../../cb/toupper
18, ../../cb/windialog
17, ../../cb/winframe
buffer is C:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp
```

It appears the issues were either due to use of non-standard functions, your pointer arithmetic on `void*` or the lack of validation on one of the steps led to a failure going unnoticed and ultimately *Undefined Behavior*.

If you always compile with warnings enabled -- the compiler would have pointed out many of those problems. For `gcc` at minimum use:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow
```

Look over the changes and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you. I responded in that chat area.

Comment: Got it. I responded there as well. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: Above you can ensure all files will be adequately handled by using `#define FN_BUF_LEN PATH_MAX` and you are good. As you found in the header, the `260` char limit only applied to the *Filename* portion of `Path + Filename`. `PATH_MAX` covers both.

Comment: Thank you. I believe this is how my issue came about. I went to the databases directory and made a file of the largest name Windows 7 would accept. The file name length is limited based upon the directory path; so, it was less than 260 (237 in my case). If I run my old code or your code, both work. If I then change the directory name, making it longer, such as "bigger databases", then my old code and your code both print the correct fl_name, including all characters, but `stat()` can't find the file. No matter what FN_BUF_LEN is set to, `stat()` won't accept more than 260.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not implying anything you told me is not correct or  not an improvement to my original code. I'm just trying to point out what my question was. The funny thing is that I went back and tried starting over with your code and couldn't recreate the error because I couldn't reach 260 again, and was quite confused. Then realized that I must've edited the directory name after adding the large test file name to the directory. I'll quite bothering you. But is there anyway to get `stat()` to accept more than 260 if a user was to do the same/similar? Thank you.

Comment: It should be pointed out also that the file name is less than 260 in all cases; and, even though pointer `p` points only to the file name as passed in `stat()`, `stat()` appears to still apply the max to `fl_name` and not just the `p`.